# php url rewriting using htaccess not working for me

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

in my project i want to rewrite the page from localhost/project/category.php to localhost/project/category. Then i created a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category?$ category.php
```

And **Its working fine**

When i try localhost/project/category.php?id=1 to localhost/project/category/1 using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+) category.php?id=$1
```

And i tried to access the **id** value using **$_GET['id']** its not getting.

**I just want to rewrite localhost/project/anypage.php to localhost/project/anypage and
localhost/project/category.php?id= to localhost/project/category/1 and access that id value**

Please help me to do it

Comment: nope..its not working